# Lower bound for the probability that $X=\omega\left(\mathbb E[X]\right)$ for $X\sim Bin(n,p)$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, lower-bounds, binomial-distribution

Let $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ be a binomial variable and let $\delta\in (0,1)$.

I'm looking for a *lower* bound of the form $\Pr[X > f(\delta)] \ge \delta$.

Specifically, if $\delta,p=o(1)$ are not constants, it seems that $f(\delta)$ should satisfy $f(\delta)=\omega(np)$.

> **Can we find any $f(\delta)=\omega(np)$ such that $\Pr[X > f(\delta)] \ge \delta$?**

---

For example, assume that $p=\delta=1/n$. Am I correct to assume that such $f=\omega(1)$ has to exist?

Comment: "For example..." I don't think so, because the Binomial$(n, 1/n)$ distribution tends to the Poisson$(1)$ distribution as $n \to \infty$, so for a given $\delta$ the corresponding $f(\delta)$ should tend to a fixed constant. Right?

Comment: @usul - I'm not sure I follow.  If $\delta$ is tiny (say $e^{-n}$), why can't we have $f(\delta)=\omega(1)$ for Poisson(1)? All that is required is that a tiny ($\delta$) fraction of the probability mass will exceed $f(\delta)$.
For example, is it not true that $\Pr[X > \log n]\ge e^{-n}$ for $X\sim$ Poisson$(1)$?

Comment: Oh, right. I somehow missed that $\delta$ is also shrinking as $n$ grows. Sorry!

Comment: What is $\omega$? How is $\delta$ supposed to be related to $n,p$? Can you state the problem formally?

Comment: If $p=\delta=1/n$ and $f=1/2$ (say), then $P(X>f)=1-P(X=0)=1-(1-1/n)^n>1-1/e>1/2\ge1/n=\delta$ for $n\ge2$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis - $\omega(1)$ means non-constant. In your example (with $f=1/2$), we get $\Pr(X>f)>1/2>\delta$, but $f$ is constant and there's a lot of "slack". I think can have $f=O(\sqrt{\log n})$ and still get $\Pr[X>f]>\delta$ (for $p=\delta=1/n$).

Comment: @RB : non-constant is essentially a non-restriction. E.g., I could replace the constant $f=1/2$ by the "barely" non-constant $f=1/2+1/10^n$. Anyhow, I think for $p=\delta=1/n$ I can get $f\sim\ln n/\ln\ln n$; would that be enough for you? If not, you would really need to state your question in a much more specific and formal manner. In particular, you would need to specify how $\delta$ is supposed to be related with $n,p$, as I requested earlier. Also, you would have to do something about the "non-constant" non-restriction.

Comment: @IosifPinelis- yes, non-constant is not the right meaning, but rather a quantity that goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity. You can think of $p,\delta$ as functions of $n$ that goes to zero as $n\to\infty$. I'm looking for a function $f$ that goes to infinity as $n$ grows such that $\Pr[X>f]>\delta$. I think it's possible to show $\Pr[X>np+O(\sqrt{np\log\delta^{-1}})]>\delta$, for any $p,\delta$. The bound you suggest seems to be stronger (even if just for the $p=\delta=1/n$ case). Please elaborate if you can.

Comment: @RB : I again suggest that you state your conjecture specifically and formally before asking for further help.